# В поисках API для сжатия изображений

Tags: api, изображения

3дpaвствyйте, я ищу api которое может сжимать изображения форматов `png`, `jpeg`, `webp` и `gif` без потери качества. Если знаете такое, то подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Сжатие жипега без потери качества невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот например https://tinypng.com/developers
А вообще можно использовать уже готовые библиотеки, а не слать данные по сети